# Javascript code completion for arango and module handling

Tags: javascript, npm, visual-studio-code, arangodb, code-completion

## Introduction

I've been using Eclipse for Java(!) development for more than a decade. Due to high demand I'm jumping in the deep end with javascript and arangodb. Task is to develop several microservices running within arangodb.

I'm free to use the IDE/Editor of my choice. Only remaining competitors are MS VS Code and IntelliJ. VS Code beeing my favorite as of writing.

## Project setup

According to arangos [documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/Manual/Foxx/GettingStarted.html) I've composed a project with:

mainfest.json (content skipped to improve readability)

package.json

```
 {
"name": "abc",
"version": "0.0.2",
"description": "foxxy service",
"comment" : "This file contains the NPM package definition",
"main": "main.js",
"directories": {
  "test": "test"
},
"dependencies": {
  "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
  "jsonq": "^1.1.0",
  "xml2js": "^0.4.19",
  "xmldom": "^0.1.27",
  "xpath.js": "^1.0.7"
 },
"devDependencies": {
  "chai": "^4.1.1",
  "mocha": "^3.5.0"
},
 "scripts": {
   "test": "node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha"
  }
}
```

jsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "checkJs": true
},
"include": [
    "scripts/**/*",
    "lib/**/*",
    "models/**/*",
    "node_modules/@arangodb/**/*",
    "node_modules/jsonq/**/*",
    "node_modules/xml2js/**/*",
    "/*"
]
}
```

---

## Current state

VS Studio Code offers code completion for:
- standard Javascript (ES6) expressions
- resolves actual files behind require expressions ( e.g.: require('lodash') is resolved to the actual filesystem path 
`C:/Users/notte/AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript/2.5/node_modules/@types/lodash/index'` *which proves (for me) that npm module resolution and code completion are working*

## Question

Arango does not offer modules via npmjs or other public repositories. I therefore copied the files ([@arangodb](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/tree/devel/js/server/modules/%40arangodb)) from an local arangodb installation to the projects "node_modules" folder.

1. Altough VS Code is informed about the [@arango modules](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/Manual/Appendix/JavaScriptModules/ArangoDB.html) and submodules it does not come up with a useful code completion. What should I do or try to do?
2. What would be a pragmatic, sustainable solution for handling modules like those from arango? (it is not present in npmjs, has no package.json and hence no versioning)

Thank you.

Comment: maybe I don't understand well your question, but, anyway  arango offer module from npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/arangojs

Comment: since sconfig.json is a descendent of tsconfig.json, which is a configuration file for TypeScript. jsconfig.json is tsconfig.json with "allowJs" attribute set to true. So probably you need a d.ts for arango, same available at https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs/blob/master/arangojs.d.ts

Comment: @InferOn: that module is not sufficient. From the first paragraph of the page you've linked to: "if you are looking for the ArangoDB JavaScript API in Foxx (or the arangosh interactive shell) please check the ArangoDB documentation instead; specifically the db object exported by the \@arangodb module. The JavaScript driver is only meant to be used when accessing ArangoDB from outside the database."

Comment: if the type definition is missing seems that intellisense doesn't work I am sorry

Answer (score 1):

We Currently collecting user efforts to create Syntax hilighting via  https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1755 - Please share your thoughts if you have something to add.